# Accessing an attribute in a template

Tags: html, django, class, object

I have an app called `loans` which has a model class named `Loan` with an attribute `start_date` in a Django project. I want to access that attribute in a template. Do I have to place it as `{{ loans.loan.start_date}}` or just `{{ loan.start_date }}`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to pass an instance of `Loan` via the context in your view code. If the name of the key you use is called `loan` then you'd be able to access `start_date` using `{{ loan.start_date }}`.

Read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/) and in particular [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render) to learn more.

Here's the minimum needed:

In `loans/views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Loan


def detail(request, loan_id):
    loan = Loan.objects.get(id=load_id)
    return render(request, 'loans/index.html', {'loan': loan})
```

In `loans/templates/loans/index.html`:

```
<p>The start date is: {{ loan.start_date }}</p>
```

Comment: I think I understand, but I have a lack of information. Could you explain to me what is an instance of a class? If you explain in such a way that I understand well, I will accept your answer.

Comment: When you do `Loan()` or `Loan.objects.first()` for e.g. then the object that is returned to you will be an instance of the class `Loan`. A class is like a blue print and the objects you create from it are called its instances.

Comment: Would you have time to build a little example to make your answer complete?

Comment: Sure, I'll do that now.

Comment: date_end is an attribute from a Django Model (i.e., DataField). Do I need to follow this procedure yet?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you send the `Loan` to your view.  Django expects the view to provide the template with a context dictionary of values that the template then uses/accesses to render the HTML response to the user.  Whatever you call that value in the context dictionary is how you reference it in your template.  For example:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class LoanView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'loan_view.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LoanView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['my_loan'] = Loan.objects.first()
        return context
```

And in loan_view.html:

```
<h1>Loan view</h1>
<ul>
    <li>Created at: {{ my_loan.start_date }}</li>
</ul>
```

n.b.  If you are using view functions it looks a little more like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def loan_view(request):
    context = {
        'my_loan': Loan.objects.first()
    }
    return render(request, 'loan_view.html', context)
```

Up above, because we used the key `my_loan` for our `Loan` object, we used `my_loan` to access that `Loan` in our template.